# Axis Labels in Pyplot Heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, axis-labels

I can make a heatmap using:

```
Index= [np.arange(0, 1, 1/5)]
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)

plt.pcolor(df)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index),   1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

How can I change the y axis labels to **'0.0   0.5   1.0'** please?

Comment: `plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), ['0.0', '', '0.5', '', '1.0'])` ?

Comment: Cheers @JohanC that works but it would be difficult to code if I had 600 rows (which I do in my real application!)

Answer (score 0):

You can label the x and y axes by using the keyword argument extent in the calls to imshow.

```
extent : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
Data limits for the axes.  //The default assigns zero-based row,
column indices to the `x`, `y` centers of the pixels.
```

working as a example you need to import all data from pylab using

```
from pylab import *
input! = rand(5,5)
figure(1)
imshow(input1, interpolation='nearest')
grid(True)

left = 7.5
right = 9.5
bottom = 7.5
top = -0.5
extent = [left, right, bottom, top]

figure(2)
imshow(input1, interpolation='nearest', extent=extent)
grid(True)

show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the yticks working

```
len_I = 50
Index= [np.arange(0, 1, 1/len_I)]
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(len_I, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)

plt.pcolor(df)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, (len(df.index)+1), len(df.index)/2), np.arange(0, len(df.index), 0.5))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.show()
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: This gives an error when you try `len_i = 49` or `len_i = 850`.

Comment: What your code does, is `plt.yticks([0, 25, 51], [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, ...])`. This puts the ytick positions at almost the right spot (it is one off, but not really visible), and provides a much too large array for the labels.  You'd get the same result with `plt.yticks([0, len(df)/2), len(df)], [0, 0.5, 1])`.

Comment: thanks, your bracket should read plt.yticks([0, len(df)/2, len(df)], [0, 0.5, 1])

Comment: Sorry, a typo in a comment. You could replace `Index= [np.arange(0, 1, 1/len_I)]` with `Index = np.linspace(0, 1, len_I)` to avoid weird errors (and remove superfluous square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

`pcolor` draws colored rectangles between grid points given by x and y positions. You need one row and one column more than there are values. You can set the x-grid at positions 0,1,2,3,4 for 4 columns, with tick positions nicely between the grid points. The y-axis can be a regular axis, where a `MultipleLocator` can set tick positions at the desired multiples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_rows = 600
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
num_cols = len(cols)
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(num_rows, num_cols).cumsum(axis=0)), columns=cols)

plt.pcolor(range(num_cols+1), np.linspace(0, 1, num_rows+1), df.to_numpy(), cmap='hot')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]